# To find an element of galois group which sends one prime ideal above $p$ to another prime ideal above $p$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $L/K$ be finite galois number field extension and $p$ be prime of (ring of integers of) $K$.
Let $G=Gal(L/K)$.

It is well known that $G$ acts transitively on the set of all prime ideals of $L$ above $p$.

The proof of this fact I know is proof by contradiction.
It goes on like,
If we assume there exists $B_1,B_2$, for all $ \sigma \in G$, $ B_1≠\sigma(B_2)$, then from Chinese reminder theorem there exists $x \in O_K$ s.t $x≡0modB_2$ and $x≡1mod \sigma B_1$.
$N_{L/K}(x)$ is in $p$, on the other hand, from hypothesis of proof by contradiction, $x$ cannot be in $p$, contradiction▪️

My question is, can't we prove by finding explicit $ \sigma \in G$, which sends one ideal over $p$ to another prime above $p$ ?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me that we couldn't, but to prove this fact constructively, we'd need to know (among other things) exactly how each prime in $K$ splits in $L$, and this is not in general an easy question to answer.

Comment: The idea of the proof is, that we do not need to know which Galois automorphism sends one prime ideal over $(p)$ to another one.

Comment: I'm not an expert on any of this, but I just don't see it working without having some kind of an explicit description of both the collection of prime ideals and the Galois group. This is rarely available. It could be made to work with compositums of quadratic extensions or cyclotomic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$. For example, the prime $p=23$ splits completely in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. Each of the four prime ideals is characterized by which of the elements in the conjugate pairs $5\pm\sqrt2$, $7\pm\sqrt3$ it contains, making the answer obvious. But more generally?

Comment: Of course it can be done since e.g. pari and sage can do this. My suggestion is working out the correspondence for primes of degee $1$ in cyclotomic fields and then verifying that things become messy pretty quickly by looking e.g. at the cubic subfield of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_7)$, say.